# How to handle error for duplicate entries?

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

I have a PHP form that enters data into my MySQL database. My primary key is one of the user-entered values. When the user enters a value that already exists in the table, the MySQL error "Duplicate entry 'entered value' for key 1" is returned.
Instead of that error, I would like to alert the user that they need to enter a different value. Just an echoed message or something.

How to turn a specific MySQL error into a PHP message?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

To check for this specific error, you need to find the [error code](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dup_key). It is `1062` for duplicate key. Then use the result from [`errno()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php) to compare with:

```
mysqli_query('INSERT INTO ...');
if (mysqli_errno() == 1062) {
    print 'no way!';
}
```

**A note on programming style**
You should always seek to avoid the use of [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) (I know, I was the one to introduce it in this answer). Instead, you could assign the known error code (`1062`) to a constant (e.g. `MYSQLI_CODE_DUPLICATE_KEY`). This will make your code easier to maintain as the condition in the `if` statement is still readable in a few months when the meaning of `1062` has faded from memory :)

Comment: Yeah, I just found that too :D I plugged it in and it worked perfectly. Thanks jensgram, just the solution I was looking for!

Comment: @jensgram: +1 thanks for very useful answer & tip.  I'm just adding this link for those using PDO: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorcode.php

Comment: For OOP it's **`$mysqli->errno`**.

Comment: to find out error number: echo mysqli_errno($link); //where link is your database connection.

Comment: Why do you spend a while paragraph on instructing the reader to use constants, instead of just (or at least in addition to) applying it to your code snippet?

Answer (score 5):

You can check the return value from `mysql_query` when you do the insert.

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('dupe')");

if (!$result) {
    echo "Enter a different value";
} else {
    echo "Save successful.";
}
```

Comment: Aha, i've seen this before, and this definitely looks right. thanks nickf!

Comment: Actually, is there any way to check if it's the specific error?

Comment: Yep - `mysql_errno()` will return the error code of the last error. Off the top of my head, I don't know what that code is, but you could just check for that inside the `(!$result)` branch.

Comment: The OOP equivalent of `mysql_errno()` is **`$mysqli->errno`**.

Answer (score 1):

try this code to handle duplicate entries and show echo message:

```
  $query = "INSERT INTO ".$table_name." ".$insertdata;
                if(mysqli_query($conn,$query)){
                    echo "data inserted into DB<br>";                   
                }else{
                   if(mysqli_errno($conn) == 1062)
                       echo "duplicate entry no need to insert into DB<br>";
                   else
                    echo "db insertion error:".$query."<br>";

                }//else end
```

Answer (score 0):

With **mysql_error()** function
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: this just turns on error reporting, as far as i can tell. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_errno()` function, it returns the error numbers. The error number for duplicate keys is 1062. 
for example

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name SET ...);
if (mysql_errno() == 1062){
    echo 'Duplicate key';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my full code that I used and works perfect. Its PDO friendly, and can handle your error easily, (once you have used die to discover what that is. Then you can copy the error message from there, and enclose it in an if. This came from a signup page, where I wanted to redirect to the login page, if the primary key (email) was found, and produced an error.

```
function insertUserDetails($email, $conn){

  try {
      $query = $conn->prepare ("INSERT INTO users (emailaddress) VALUES (:email)");
            $query ->bindValue('email', $email);
            $query->execute();
        }
  catch (PDOException $e) {

      if(str_contains($e, '1062 Duplicate entry')) {
          header("Location: login.php");

      }
          die("Error inserting user details into database: " .  $e->getMessage());

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  INSERT **IGNORE** into sales(id,order_date,amount)
  values(1, '2021-01-01', 250)
```

**the IGNORE parameter stops generating and error but the duplicate entry is still not allowed.**

```
$affectedRows = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
$newRowId = mysqli_insert_id($dbConn);
```

**To error check If duplcate entry without php or mysql raising error** ...

```
  /* -------------------------------------------------------
    the function that will securely place the new data
    into the database table
  ------------------------------------------------------- */
function insertIntoDatabase($dbConn, $tablename, $userData) 
{
  /*
    Generate placeholders for prepared statement 
    [$userData] is associate array ie    "firstname" => "henry"
    with the part left of => being the exact database column
    name and the part right of => being value inserted in column
  */
  $placeholders = rtrim(str_repeat('?, ', count($userData)), ', ');
  // Generate comma-separated list of column names
  $columns = implode(', ', array_keys($userData));
  // Construct the SQL query for insertion
  $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO $tablename ($columns) VALUES ($placeholders)";
  // Prepare the SQL statement
  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbConn, $sql);
  // Bind parameters to the prepared statement
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, str_repeat('s', count($userData)), ...array_values($userData));
  // Execute the prepared statement to insert data into the database
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

   /*
    feedback on success or faliure
    if [$affectedRows] = 0 and ][$newRowId] = 0
    then we know nothing was added to database
   */
  $affectedRows = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
  $newRowId = mysqli_insert_id($dbConn);

  return [$affectedRows, $newRowId];
}
```

refer to https://vb6code.com/code-php-insert-data-into-mysql-database.php