# Display error message in php for MYSQL duplicate error

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1062

I am using `UNIQUE Constraint` in my table for two columns to prevent duplicate rows. If I try to insert a row with the same 2 columns I get

> A Database Error Occurred Error
>   Number: 1062
>
> Duplicate entry '62-88' for key
>   'subscription'
>
> INSERT INTO `subscriptions`
>   (`user_id`, `subscribed_to`, `date`)
>   VALUES ('62', '88', '2011-07-11
>   19:15:13')
>
> Filename:
>   C:\wamp\www\mysite\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

How can I return a php error, e..g `Already subscribed!` instead of displaying the mysql error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handle error for duplicate entries - PHP MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146838/handle-error-for-duplicate-entries-php-mysql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call [`mysql_errno()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-errno.php) after your `mysql_query()` and check for `1062`.

**Note:** It's a more common/intuitive solution to query the database first. See answer by **Manocho**.

Comment: +1: The fewer trips between the database & the application, the better.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm using an MVC pattern. If I understood correctly, I add `mysql_errno()` after my `insert ` query (in my model) and that should return `1062`? Then I would use `if ($query == 1062)` display error?

Comment: Yes. You could put it in your Model. But I'd argue this is business logic and it may be better served in your Controller. Note, check if `mysql_errno()` returns `1062`, not the query.

Comment: Where is the answer by Manocho?

Answer (score 5):

I think you will need to run a query manually to check if the entry already exists in your database. so something like: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM subscriptions WHERE (user_id = '62' AND subscribed_to = '88')`. If the count returned is > 0 then return the error, however you want it displayed.

Comment: @Jason 's response is actually more efficient than mine, though both would work.

Comment: The fewer trips between the database & the application, the better.

Answer (score 1):

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php I assume you are able to programatically obtain the MySQL error
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-errno.php
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-handling.html

Using the 3rd link, compare the mysql error or mysql errno to the list of errors and if the condition is met, provide your alternate error message.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error you can do this:

```
mysql_query($sql);

if (mysql_errno() == 1062) {       
  print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"; 
  print "alert('The informations are already inserted')"; 
  print "</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
  $query = "INSERT INTO ".$table_name." ".$insertdata;
                if(mysqli_query($conn,$query)){
                    echo "data inserted into DB<br>";                   
                }else{
                   if(mysqli_errno($conn) == 1062)
                       echo "duplicate entry no need to insert into DB<br>";
                   else
                    echo "db insertion error:".$query."<br>";

                }//else end
```