# I want to show an error if duplicates are there in database using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to show an error while entering duplicates using php and mysql, but i'm not getting how to complete, please give an solution........

this is my code:

```
mysql_query(
"INSERT INTO productcost (product, productCategory, model, purchasePrice, mrp, customerPrice, marginCustomer, dealerPrice, marginDealer) 
VALUES ('" . $_POST["product"] . "','" . $_POST["productCategory"] . "','" . $_POST["model"] . "','" . $_POST["purchasePrice"] . "','" . $_POST["mrp"] . "','" . $_POST["customerPrice"] . "','" . $_POST["marginCustomer"] . "','" . $_POST["dealerPrice"] . "', '" . $_POST["marginDealer"] . "')");

$current_id = mysql_insert_id();

if(!empty($current_id)) {
$message = "New Product Added Successfully";
}
```

}

Comment: Before insert statement create a select statement with product,productCategory,model. Ignore the insert query if select query returns anything.

Comment: What is your primary key?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handle error for duplicate entries - PHP MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146838/handle-error-for-duplicate-entries-php-mysql)

Comment: Hi Ajmedway, i have not made any primary key....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to create unique  key in productcost table , using unique fields  like (product, productCategory, model). Now execute insert query, if there is a recode in the table return error . now you can handle error and give message.

```
    try{ 
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO productcost (product_key_id,product, productCategory,model,purchasePrice, mrp, customerPrice, marginCustomer, dealerPrice, marginDealer) 
VALUES 
('" . $_POST["created_product_id"] . "','" . $_POST["product"] . "','".$_POST["productCategory"] . "','" . $_POST["model"] . "','".$_POST["purchasePrice"] . "','" . $_POST["mrp"] . "','".$_POST["customerPrice"] . "','" . $_POST["marginCustomer"] . "','".$_POST["dealerPrice"] . "', '" . $_POST["marginDealer"] . "')");

    return TRUE;
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
      return FALSE;
    }
```

or you can check is there a recode in table  before insert

```
select count(*) as cc from doc_upload where product_key_id = $_POST["created_product_id"];
```

Comment: Yes Sravan, you have to add new column for  product_key_id.
you can create value for product_key_id using your product id, productCategory id and model id like this (product id = 10,productCategory id = 251 and model id = Q0111 now your product_key_id = '10251Q0111') .

catch(Exception $e){

    $errors = $e->mysql_error();
    }

Comment: catch(Exception $e){

    $errors = $e->mysql_error();
   return  $errors;
    }

$errors is an array .

Comment: and what my concern is product name may be same for different models, if i enter same product twice with different model it should be stored in database......so i'm not getting correct solution for this, please suggest anyone.....can i use (mysql_errno()==1062) for this?? and how??

Answer (score -2):

**To show an error message while entering duplicates:**

```
// First check there are same data available or not using a query by counting the row
$sqlCheck = "SELECT COUNT(`id`) WHERE product = '" . $_POST["product"] . "' AND productCategory = '" . $_POST["productCategory"] . "' AND model = '" . $_POST["model"] . "'"; // You have to add mroe thing in where clause
$CheckQuery = mysql_query($sqlCheck);

// if there is no duplicate data
// 
if ($CheckQuery > 0) {
    # code...

mysql_query(
"INSERT INTO productcost (product, productCategory, model, purchasePrice, mrp, customerPrice, marginCustomer, dealerPrice, marginDealer) 
VALUES ('" . $_POST["product"] . "','" . $_POST["productCategory"] . "','" . $_POST["model"] . "','" . $_POST["purchasePrice"] . "','" . $_POST["mrp"] . "','" . $_POST["customerPrice"] . "','" . $_POST["marginCustomer"] . "','" . $_POST["dealerPrice"] . "', '" . $_POST["marginDealer"] . "')");

$current_id = mysql_insert_id();

if(!empty($current_id)) {

    $message = "New Product Added Successfully";

}

} else {

        $message = "Data is Duplicated";
}
```

> Note : I'm Giving you an Example . this is how you have to check
>   duplicate data

Comment: You're doing 2 round trips to the database and two primary key look-ups here. A more standard way of doing this would be to attempt the INSERT and if there's an error catch the error and display the error messag.e

Comment: Thank you anirud............but Ben is suggesting to try and catch blocks......can you please suggest on this......