# How to get en error message if record exists Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem with proper error message (message when exists) in sql query which should insert records when not exist...

for example:

```
 INSERT INTO list (code, name, address,)
SELECT 'ABC', 'ABC name', 'Johannesburg'
FROM list
   WHERE NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT code, name, address
   FROM list
   WHERE code = 'ABC'
   AND name = 'ABC name'
   AND address = 'Johannesburg'
     )
LIMIT 1



if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){

    echo "Records added successfully.";

} else{

    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);

}
```

is it possible to make extra error message which would tell if this record already exists?

thank you for any advices

Comment: Yes, it is possible and requires a lot more code.

Comment: yes, you check the error code returned by `mysqli_errno()` and see if it's the specific code that means "duplicate key".

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3146986/3055401