# How to find a duplicate record in a specific column of a table and redirect an error page in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

There is a table named "enrolled_students_info" in database. It has 7 columns. One of its columns is set to `UNIQUE`. If i enter a duplicate value in that column, it will not enter. But all i want is, Not to INSERT the whole field in case if the record value is duplicating and redirect to another page (values of other columns may repeat).
I've used the following method in past to redirect to another page in case if the value is repeating, but at that time the table was consisted of only 1 column

```
if($con->affected_rows === 0){
  header("location:error.php");
}
```

But now, there are seven columns and this method is not working.

Comment: you can perform the select statement and check if the record already exist like "Select count(*) from enrolled_students_info where id=1"

Answer (score 1):

If you attempt to insert a duplicate entry on a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY, you will get a duplicate key error. Checking for this error (by the error code - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146838/handle-error-for-duplicate-entries-php-mysql)) in your is the correct way of handling this error. You will not get a duplicated row inserted.

Attempting to `SELECT count(*) ..` or any other post process will never return true, and as a pre-INSERT is subject to race conditions between it and connection could be concurrently inserting. Never do this. Use the database to manage concurrency as that's what its designed to do.