# PHP MySQL GET RESULT from INSERT INTO IF NOT EXIST

Tags: php, mysql, insert, output

I know how to do INSERT INTO if the record doesn't exist.
But if it does exist, mysql doesn't treat it as an error.  It just treats it as 0 rows inserted.
I want to know if that was the case and return that message to the user that the data they submitted already exists.

I know I can do it if I first query mysql before I attempt to insert the new data.  However, is there a way to do it with the INSERT and get a result?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... please show us some code you tried and more detail about it. Take look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask a better question.

Comment: Unless you use `INSERT IGNORE` or `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, you should get an error if you try to create a duplicate record.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle error for duplicate entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146838/how-to-handle-error-for-duplicate-entries)

Comment: You can call `AFFECTED_ROWS()` to get the number of rows that were inserted. PDO and mysqli have functions that return this.

Comment: I am not using a primary key to match.  I am actually matching 2 fields.  If both exist, then it is considered a duplicate.

Comment: $sql="INSERT INTO common_repairs (isp_id, repair_name)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '$ispid', '$newrepair') AS temp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT repair_name FROM common_repairs WHERE repair_name = '$newrepair' AND isp_id='$ispid'
) LIMIT 1";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) in which case [mysqli::$affected_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) should return 1 if the row is inserted as a new row, 2 if an existing row is updated, and 0 if an existing row is set to its current values ([source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-affected-rows.html#:%7E:text=duplicate%20was%20deleted.-,For%20INSERT%20...%20ON%20DUPLICATE%20KEY%20UPDATE%20statements%2C%20the%20affected%2Drows,if%20an%20existing%20row%20is%20set%20to%20its%20current%20values.,-Following%20a%20CALL)).
So your code should be something like:

```
if ($mysqli->affected_rows == 1) {
                    
    $inserted = true;
}

if ($mysqli->affected_rows == 2) {
        
    $updated = true;
}
```

Comment: I just tried this, and now matter what, it returns 0. 2 is irrelevant since, I am only INSERTING and not UPDATING.    Here is my SQL. `code` $sql="INSERT INTO common_repairs (isp_id, repair_name)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '$ispid', '$newrepair') AS temp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT repair_name FROM common_repairs WHERE repair_name = '$newrepair' AND isp_id='$ispid'
) LIMIT 1"; `/code`

Comment: Which fields are your keys in the common_repairs table? isp_id?

Comment: If I understood your query correctly (it seems it's more complicated than it could be) you could possibly add isp_id, repair_name as a unique index (ALTER TABLE common_repairs ADD UNIQUE my_unique_index (isp_id, repair_name);) so when you do simple $sql = "INSERT INTO common_repairs (isp_id, repair_name) VALUES ('$ispid', '$newrepair')"; mysqli::$affected_rows will simply return 1 if inserted (the pair doesn't exist) or 0 if it's not inserted (the pair already exists). Hope that makes sense.